# OpenLDAP ACL problem with regex - server stops

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have basic OpenLDAP server installation on my windows desktop. I want to make ACL rule that will do:

```
ou = Outer
   ou = Inner1
     uid = uid1
     uid = uid2
   ou = Inner2
     uid = uid1
     uid = uid2
```

uid=uid1,ou=Inner1,ou=Outer to self write and don't see other objects inside Outer.

Currently I have something like this and it crushes the server.

```
access to dn.regex=".+,ou=([^,]+),ou=Outer,dc=maxcrc,dc=com$"
   by self write
   by * none
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at the log, and the documentation. Off topic.

Comment: Why not `access to dn.children="ou=Inner1,ou=Outer,dc=maxcrc,dc=com" by self write by * none` ?